# iAd freezes game's scene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad

I am developing a game using SpriteKit. I have iAds displayed in a view on the scene. When an ad in the  Ad view is touched, the Ad appears, however, if I cross(X)/close the ad the scene in the game is frozen. I do not pause the scene or do anything on the events when the Ad appears and disappears. If I touch the ad again (now this is second time with frozen scene) and return to the scene, the scene un-freezes and everything starts to work as they were suppose to (strangely). I am not sure where is the problem in iAd or my app?

```
// Method is called when the iAd is loaded.
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"Banner did load");
    [self animateAdBanner];
}

-(void) animateAdBanner{

if(iAdsEnable){

    [UIView animateWithDuration:6 delay:8
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
        animations:^{
            [self.adBanner setAlpha:0.85];
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            if(finished){
             //[self.adBanner setAlpha:0.7];
            }

        }];



}
}
```

Comment: Can I see where you create your bannerview, and perhaps also your viewcontroller viewdidload?

Comment: I am doing nothing in 'ViewDidLoad'. The banner view was created using 'Storyboard' not programmatically.

Comment: The behaviour has been detected on device (IPhone 5, IOS 7.1). In the simulator, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's ADBannerViewDelegate Protocol Reference:

```
bannerViewActionShouldBegin:willLeaveApplication:
```

> If the willLeave parameter is YES, then your application is moved to the background shortly after this method returns. In this situation, your method implementation does not need to perform additional work. If willLeave is set to NO, then the triggered action will cover your application’s user interface to show the advertising action. Although your application continues to run normally, your implementation of this method should disable activities that require user interaction while the action is executing. For example, a **game might pause its game play** until the user finishes watching the advertisement.

Basically meaning that as your game is pushed into the background, the game will pause.

The delegate has a further method to notify you when the banner view has finished its action:

```
bannerViewActionDidFinish:
```

> Discussion
>   If your delegate paused activities before allowing an action to run, it should resume those activities when this method is called.

It seems you can either use the above delegate methods to implement your own pause/un-pause or you could use the a NSNotification in your Scene to pause/un-pause when your app moves into the background and foreground respectively.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
addObserver:self
selector:@selector(pause)
name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
addObserver:self
selector:@selector(unPause)
name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
object:nil];
```

Sources:
[iAd Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/iAd_ReferenceCollection/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009705) and [ADBannerViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/ADBannerViewDelegate/bannerViewActionDidFinish%3a)